# calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\log^n(x)\log(1+\frac{b^{2}}{x^{2}})dx=? (n\in N^* , b\geq2)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

> calculate $$\int_{0}^{\infty}(\log(x))^{n}\log(1+\frac{b^{2}}{x^{2}})dx=?  (n\in N^*, b\geq2)$$

for $n=1$:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\log(x)\log(1+\frac{b^2}{x^2})dx&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\log(x)\log(\frac{x^2+b^2}{x^2})dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\log(x)(\log(x^2+b^2)-\log(x^2))dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\log(x)\{\log(x^2+b^2)\}_{0}^{b}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\log(x)\int_{0}^{b}\frac{2t}{x^2+t^2}dtdx\\
&=\int_{0}^{b}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2t\log(x)}{t^2+x^2}dxdt\\
&=\int_{0}^{b}\frac{2t\pi\log(t)}{2t}dt\\
&=\pi\int_{0}^{b}\log(t)dt=\pi\{t\log(t)-t\}_{0}^{b}\\
&=\pi b(\log(b)-1)\\
\end{align*}

Wait for your help $n\geq2$

Comment: Your computation is probably incorrect because for $n=1,b=1$ the result seems to be $-\pi$.

Comment: Yes b>1 not $b=1$

Comment: You meant $(\log x)^n$ I guess because $\log(x)^n = n\log x$

Comment: Yes $(\log(x))^n$ I will explain that

Comment: Sorry  actually your formula works for $b=1$ as well (for a moment i was thinking $\ln(1)=1$ , silly me !)

Comment: Your problem is to evaluate integrals of the form: $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^n x}{b^2+x^2}dx$. i think one can evaluate them using Euler's beta function.

Comment: @FDPNotice well in the comments on the first there is an error in writing but the integration is for$n\in N^*$and $b\geq2$

Comment: @Bachamohamed, your steps for n=1 are correct , you need to use Euler beta function as FDP claimed above to get your reccurence formula and the general fortmula would uses Logarithm integral function

Comment: @zeraoulia rafik yes I try on that

Comment: @AmanRajput It's actually a common notation (especially for programming people) that $(\log x )^n = \log(x)^n$. This is because there is a bunch of people (like me) which prefer () brackets around arguments of function (like in programming). If you want to raise to a power the argument, then simply use the upper index inside the brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{n}\pars{x} \over
x^{2} + t^{2}}\,\dd x} =
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{n}\pars{x} \over x^{2} + t^{2}}\,\dd x +
\int_{1}^{0}{\ln^{n}\pars{1/x} \over \pars{1/x}^{2} + t^{2}}\,
\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{n}\pars{x} \over x^{2} + t^{2}}\,\dd x +
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over t^{2}}
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{n}\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1/t^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[10px,#eef]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{n}\pars{x} \over x^{2} + t^{2}}\,\dd x} +
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over t^{2}}\pars{t \mapsto {1 \over t}}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#eef]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{n}\pars{x} \over x^{2} + t^{2}}\,\dd x} =
-\,{1 \over t}\,\Im\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{n}\pars{x} \over \ic t - x}\,\dd x =
-\,{1 \over t}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\large -\ic/t}{\ln^{n}\pars{\ic tx} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{n \over t}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\large -\ic/t}
\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\ln^{n - 1}\pars{\ic tx}\,\dd x =
-\,{n\pars{n - 1} \over t}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\large -\ic/t}
\mrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{x}\ln^{n - 2}\pars{\ic tx}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{n\pars{n - 1}\pars{n - 2} \over t}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\large -\ic/t}
\mrm{Li}_{4}'\pars{x}\ln^{n - 3}\pars{\ic tx}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] &\ = \cdots =
{n\pars{n - 1}\pars{n - 2}\cdots 1 \over t}\,\pars{-1}^{n + 1}
\,\Im\int_{0}^{\large -\ic/t}\mrm{Li}_{n + 1}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{-1}^{n + 1}n!\,{\Im\mrm{Li}_{n + 1}\pars{-\ic/t} \over t}
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{n}\pars{x} \over
x^{2} + t^{2}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pars{-1}^{n + 1}n! \over t}\,\Im\mrm{Li}_{n + 1}\pars{-\,{\ic \over t}} +
{\pars{-1}^{n} \over t^{2}}{\pars{-1}^{n + 1}n! \over 1/t}
\,\Im\mrm{Li}_{n + 1}\pars{-\,{\ic \over 1/t}}
\\[5mm] = &\
n!\,{\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,\Im\mrm{Li}_{n + 1}\pars{-\ic/t} -
\Im\mrm{Li}_{n + 1}\pars{-\ic t} \over t}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^{n}\pars{x}
\ln\pars{1 + {b^{2} \over x^{2}}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
2n!\int_{0}^{b}\bracks{\pars{-1}^{n + 1}
\,\Im\mrm{Li}_{n + 1}\pars{-\,{\ic \over t}} -
\Im\mrm{Li}_{n + 1}\pars{-\ic t}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{2n!\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,\Re\int_{-\infty\ic}^{-\ic/b}
{\mrm{Li}_{n + 1}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x -
2n!\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,\Re\int_{0}^{-\ic b}\mrm{Li}_{n + 1}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{2n!\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,
\mathcal{I}_{n + 1}\pars{-\,{\ic \over b}} -
2n!\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\,\mathcal{J}_{n + 1}\pars{\ic b}}
\\[5mm]  &\ \left.\mbox{where}\ 
\left\{\begin{array}{rclcl}
\ds{\mathcal{I}_{m}\pars{z}} & \ds{\equiv} &
\ds{\int_{-\infty\ic}^{z}
{\mrm{Li}_{m}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\,{\mrm{Li}_{m}\pars{z} \over z} + \mathcal{I}_{m - 1}\pars{z}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mathcal{J}_{m}\pars{z}} & \ds{\equiv} &
\ds{\int_{0}^{z}\mrm{Li}_{m}\pars{x}\,\dd x}  & \ds{=} &
\ds{\phantom{-}z\,\mrm{Li}_{m}\pars{z} -
\mathcal{J}_{m - 1}\pars{z}}
\end{array}\right.\right\vert_{\ m\ \geq\ 2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

$$\int _0^{\infty }\ln ^n\left(x\right)\:\ln \left(1+\frac{b^2}{x^2}\right)\:dx=\int _0^{\infty }\ln ^n\left(x\right)\:\ln \left(b^2+x^2\right)\:dx-2\int _0^{\infty }\ln ^{n+1}\left(x\right)\:dx$$
Now consider the following definition of the beta function
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{x^{\alpha -1}}{\left(1+x\right)^{\beta }}\:dx=\text{B}\left(\alpha ,\beta -\alpha \right)$$
Now using the sub $x=\frac{x^2}{b^2}$ gets
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{x^{2\alpha -1}}{\left(b^2+x^2\right)^{\beta }}\:dx=\frac{1}{2}b^{2\alpha -2\beta }\text{B}\left(\alpha ,\beta -\alpha \right)$$
Using these definitions gets us
$$\int _0^{\infty }\ln ^n\left(x\right)\:\ln \left(b^2+x^2\right)\:dx=-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 1/2 \\\beta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\partial ^{n+1}}{\partial \alpha ^n\partial \beta }b^{2\alpha -2\beta }\text{B}\left(\alpha ,\beta -\alpha \right)$$
$$-2\int _0^{\infty }\ln ^{n+1}\left(x\right)\:dx=-2\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 1 \\\beta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\partial ^{n+1}}{\partial \alpha ^{n+1}}\text{B}\left(\alpha ,\beta -\alpha \right)$$
Collecting both results gives us the not so nice generalizaton for your integral
$$\int _0^{\infty }\ln ^n\left(x\right)\:\ln \left(1+\frac{b^2}{x^2}\right)\:dx$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 1/2 \\\beta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\partial ^{n+1}}{\partial \alpha ^n\partial \beta }b^{2\alpha -2\beta }\text{B}\left(\alpha ,\beta -\alpha \right)-2\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 1 \\\beta\rightarrow 0}\frac{\partial ^{n+1}}{\partial \alpha ^{n+1}}\text{B}\left(\alpha ,\beta -\alpha \right)$$
Putting this on mathematica for $n=1$ $b=1$
gives me
$$-\frac{1}{4}\left(2\pi \psi \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)-2\pi \psi \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)-0$$
$$=-\frac{1}{4}\left(4\pi -2\pi \gamma -4\pi \ln \left(2\right)+2\pi \gamma +4\pi \ln \left(2\right)\right)=-\pi $$
Which agrees with the result mentioned by FDP.